# Boolean not rendering

Tags: boolean-modifier

I'm trying to cut out some windows in this tower I'm modeling. I used two cubes in a standard boolean method. But one of them isn't rendering and I don't know why. They work in the viewport, but not when rendering. Check out the stills

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't know what to do!

-George

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Hi, the question is clear but it will help a lot to include the .blend file using this link: https://blend-exchange.com/ 
So the other user will be able to download your file and find what's wrong.